# Why are StackAuth methods not returning rate-limit headers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackauth

Visiting the page: `http://stackauth.com/1.1/sites` yields the following headers:

[image]

Notably absent are the `X-RateLimit-Max` and `X-RateLimit-Current` headers that show up in API queries to the sites themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, as everything on Stack Auth is "query when needed (which is rarely), cache for a day", the inclusion of rate limit headers is kind of pointless.

Basically, if you *ever* need to check that you aren't hitting your quota... you're probably doing something wrong.  There are naturally exceptions, but still in 99% of all cases the headers are pointless.

If Stack Auth ever grows methods that merit more aggressive calling, it'll gain some indication of rate limiting.

Comment: Well, one of my example scripts is designed to pull the rate limit from the last request's headers. When that happens to be a request with StackAuth, I am without that information... which is unfortunate.

Comment: @George - The StackAuth 1.0 methods behave(d) the same way, its not a 1.1 change.